# RX580 not detected in ubuntu after installing amdgpu-pro

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, amd-gpu

I installed amdgpu-pro following the official tutorial [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx). I was able to check that amdgpu-pro was installed correctly by `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` with `ii`. However, when I use `radeontop` to check my GPU status it couldn't be detected. I figured it might be `radeontop`'s problem so I used other GPU monitoring scripts and none of them successfully register my GPU.

Also, when I tried to test OpenCL with [this example](https://laanwj.github.io/assets/2016/05/06/opencl-ubuntu1604/hello.c), this came up
`Error: Failed to create a device group!`

I am using radeon RX580 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I guess I can change the topic, since the subsequent question is really "Tensorflow detects GPU but is not using it"

Comment: Sorry - I managed to miss the OpenCL bit. This probably is on topic here so I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my RX580 on Ubuntu 16.04, make sure that grub is booting the graphic card on startup. Depending on what version of amdgpu-pro you are running you may need different kernel version. I have tested on kernel 4.4.0-137 the amdgpu-pro 17.50 works without any problem. Any amdgpu-pro above 17.50 you need the kernel version 4.13.

Update your kernel and try to re-install amdgpu-pro. Here is on how to update your kernel.

For Desktop

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 -y
```

For Server

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 -y
```

Comment: Also here some tip on installing the RX580, run this command for pre Vega10 cards ./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=legacy